# Why do I have to use std::make_pair?

Tags: c++, c++11, path-finding

I have already used typedef

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> coords;
typedef std::pair<float, coords> fcoords;
```

and then created a vector of this data type

```
std::vector<fcoords> openList;
```

so when I try to add an element to the vector, why do I have to do it with make_pair

```
int i = _start.first;
int j = _start.second;
```

```
openList.push_back(std::make_pair(0.0, std::make_pair(i, j)));
```

Why can I not do it by just adding the values in?

```
openList.push_back(0.0f, (i, j));
```

Comment: It looks like a structure to your eyes, but the comma is actually an operator like "+" or "/" when you use it in an expression. And "stuff in parenthesis" is an expression. The comma operator returns the value after a comma. so to the compiler, the expression is "push_back(0, (j))" which reduces to "push_back(0, j)" . Why? I'm not privy to the design designs in a language with a 50-year history, but the workaround in the answers is a nice one.

Comment: I would recommend you to NOT use pair, use Structure instead as elements can have meaningful names. To `access` the second of `coords` you have to write
`openList[1].second.second` which is very hard to read. It can be written as
`openList[1].coords.y` instead which looks great.
https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Structs_vs._Tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

```
openList.push_back({0.0f, {i, j}});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, and was such a simple fix. The worst thing was, I knew this in the back of my head :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
openList.emplace_back(0.0f, coords{i, j});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can but you need to use a correct syntax. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

typedef std::pair<int, int> coords;
typedef std::pair<float, coords> fcoords;

int main() 
{
    std::vector<fcoords> v;

    v.push_back( { 1.0f, { 2, 3 } } );

    decltype( auto ) front = v.front();

    std::cout << front.first << ": " 
              << front.second.first << ", " 
              << front.second.second << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1: 2, 3
```

As for this statement

```
openList.push_back(0.0f, (i, j));
```

then there is used a call of the member function `push_back` with two arguments instead of one argument. The first argument is the float literal `0.0f` and the second argument in an expression with the comma operator `(i, j)` the result of which is `j`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, and was such a simple fix. The worst thing was, I knew this in the back of my head :D